# Meaning of c# function parameter using double colon?

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

Seemingly in c# you can call a function and pass it a variable with a double colon syntax like so:  `foo(bar: "example")`, what is this syntax called?

And,

in the `GetReleasesAsync` function call below, by the `expand:`  I would like to pass two variables as opposed passing only one like below, what is the syntax to pass more than one variable? For example something like `expand: {ReleaseExpands.Variables, ReleaseExpands.Artifacts}` with (curly) brackets?

```
List<WebApiRelease> azureReleases = await ReleaseHttpClient.GetReleasesAsync(project: _projectName, expand: ReleaseExpands.Variables, top: 100);
```

Comment: `Named Arguments` is what you are looking for in your first question. It is more syntactic sugar which leads to a "better" readability.

Comment: And for the second part: I think what you are looking for is a bit pattern, i.e. the combination of several input flags. This is done by separating the flags with a pipe sign. That is: expand: ReleaseExpands.Variables | ReleaseExpands.Artifacts

Comment: @rmfeldt the pipe sign is just what I needed! Ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Named Arguments` is what you are looking for in your first question. It is more syntactic sugar which leads to a "better" readability.

`expand` is a Flags enum. therefore `expand: ReleaseExpands.Variables | ReleaseExpands.Artifacts` should work as parameter value to provide both values.

Like

```
List<WebApiRelease> azureReleases = await ReleaseHttpClient.GetReleasesAsync(project: _projectName, expand: ReleaseExpands.Variables | ReleaseExpands.Artifacts, top: 100);
```

Comment: `It is more syntactic sugar which leads to a "better" readability.` It also makes passing a later optional argument without specifying an earlier one possible. Which isn't really a _readability_ issue.